# Implementation of a 3D convolutional neural network

Tags: python, tensorflow, deep-learning, conv-neural-network

I'm trying to implement [this approach](http://www.cs.toronto.edu/~urtasun/publications/luo_etal_cvpr18.pdf) 
for object detection and tracking. And I can't wrap my mind around the details. I tried to look for reviews and explaination for this article. What I don't undersand is this:

> For temporal information, we take all the 3D points from the past 5 timestamps. Thus our input is a 4 dimensional tensor consisting of time, height, X and Y. For both our early-fusion and late-fusion models, we train from scratch using Adam optimizer with a learning rate of 1e-4. The model is trained on a 4 Titan XP GPU server with batch size of 12

I know that a CNN input is the following

> [batch_size, channels, X, Y]

but here they are considering

> [time, channels, X, Y]

and then they mention the batch size is 12! What i dont understand is where are they considering the batch_size and what does it represent for the 5 timestamps.

I hope someone can provide insights.

Since their dataset is not open source, I'm working on KITTI tracking benchmark.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you consider [`tf.nn.conv3d`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/nn/conv3d), the Input shape is:

> Shape [batch, in_depth, in_height, in_width, in_channels]

You can see where the batch dimension goes and you can treat `in_depth` as you wish. For temporal tasks, you can say that this represents some time steps.

---

Okay, specifically in their case. They have a point cloud. Each point (or voxel) is in an `(X, Y)` position. This data point also has `height`. They are very specific on saying:

> "[...] and treat the **height** dimension as the **channel** dimension"

So, if we use *channels-last* notation (as the default TensorFlow docs), we have `[X, Y, height]` (i.e., **3D points**). Then, they say:

> "[...] For temporal information, we take all the **3D points** from the past 5 timestamps"

That means we need a temporal dimension, e.g., `[time, X, Y, height]`, which is exactly what they said (except they used *channels-first* notation). With this 4D tensor, we can use 3D convolutions. However, we usually need them to operate on **batches of samples** rather than **single samples**. Hence the batch dimension: `[batch, time, X, Y, height]`. In their case, specifically, they train with `[12, 5, X, Y, height]`, where `batch=12` and `time=5`.

Comment: from what I understand that their input is a 4D tensor, so they are using `tf.nn.conv2d`

Comment: @Barriel can you elaborate on that please? i'm not sure I understood

Comment: @OneManArmy Let X be an input with dimensions [time, height, width, channel]. If in a batch you have N samples (batch_size=N), then the effective dimension of the input will be [batch_size=N, time, height, width, channels].

Comment: @Barriel thank you for your explaination. but the way you put it you have to use 3D convolution with `tf.nn.conv3d` since your input the way you put it have dimension 5. But in the paper they are using 2D convolution (if I understood it correctly) so the tensor has 4 dimension, this is what I couldn't figure out.

Comment: @OneManArmy No, they say "Our approach is a one-stage detector that takes a 4D tensor created from multiple consecutive temporal frames as input", which is quite clear that they did what I suggested. N-D convolutions operate on N+1 volumes (e.g., 2D conv for images). The fact that they operate on a N+2 volume is a matter of implementation w.r.t. handling the batch.

Comment: @OneManArmy I added more details in the answer specifically about your case. Can you take a look and see if this answers you additional question? Consider upvoting if any of this is useful.

Comment: @Barriel thank you for your answer, it explains alot, but what is still ambiguous is the timestamps, is it somehow related to the batch_size? Let's say you have a frame for one timestamp, so if you take 5 timestamps doesn't that mean you take batch_size = 5?

Comment: @OneManArmy No, the batch and time dimensions are different and not correlated. For instance, you can have 1 sample with 5 timestamps or a batch of 12 samples with 5 timestamps each. Sometimes, not that often, people arrange their batches as a sequence of frames, but this is not the case in this paper.

Comment: thank you for the explaination. Allow me to ask another question, in the article they said they applied a 2D conv on the voxel grid to reduce it dimensions as it point cloud data are very sparse, then they appended multiple frame (5 frames) along with a temporal axis and they they applied a 1D conv on the temporal information and then they applied the 3D input (like you said), so my question is are the last 3 mentioned convolutions are done "inside" or "outside" the neural network. Thank you

Comment: @OneManArmy it is hard to know what you mean by inside/outside. In practice, you can implement a single model with a single forward to do that (which I think you'd consider as "inside").

Comment: what I meant by that is: at one point you have your input to feed it to the NN to do some series of convolutions on it. Like you said they are doing a 3D conv on a tensor with [batch, time, X, Y, Channel], but before that they applied a 2D conv to reduce size and 1D conv on time axis, my question is the input of the NN is 4D tensor after they applied the 2D conv et 1D conv or the input of the NN is a 4D tensor and they do the 2D conv, 1D, conv, and 3D, "inside" (after injecting the 4D tensor) in the NN? I hope I made myself clearer

Comment: @OneManArmy what I meant is that you can implement this in several ways. The particular way they did, I don't know (you can always e-mail the authors). What I said is that you can implement with everything "inside".

Comment: can we discuss more about the paper? I could really use your help. thx

Comment: @OneManArmy we could, but only chats are appropriate for this kind of discussion. Feel free to create one and invite me. Also, consider marking this as answer so others can see it.

Comment: since i don't have enough reputation, I wasn't able to create a new room. is there anyway that you create the room and invite me?